# Java crashes when loading shader

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

(Ooh, this question got on the email list of "new lwjgl questions" - Awesome)

I am trying to load some shaders.

But when I do, java crashes:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x073af8f2, pid=17240, tid=16060
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig7icd32.dll+0x3df8f2]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\Downloads\mcp\ship\Ship\hs_err_pid17240.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I pastebinned the .log folder at http://pastebin.com/jnNd4UBi. But the relevant bit is:

```
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.nglLinkProgram(IJ)V+0
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glLinkProgram(I)V+15
j      utility.ShaderLoader.loadShaderPair(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/S tring;)I+887
j  Joehot200.TerrainDemo.setUpShaders()V+12
j  Joehot200.TerrainDemo.startGame()V+43
j  StartScreenExperiments.Test2.resartTDemo()V+21
j  StartScreenExperiments.Test2.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+10
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

So the relevant part is "glLinkProgram", which is showing that the crash is occurring when I attempt to link the already-compiled shaders.

My LoadShaderPair() method contains the following:

```
 public static int loadShaderPair(String vertexShaderLocation, String fragmentShaderLocation,   String tesShaderLocation, String tesscontrolShaderLocation) {
    int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    int tesscontrolShader = glCreateShader(GL40.GL_TESS_CONTROL_SHADER);
    int tesShader = glCreateShader(GL40.GL_TESS_EVALUATION_SHADER);
    StringBuilder vertexShaderSource = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder fragmentShaderSource = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder tesShaderSource = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder tesscontrolShaderSource = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader tesShaderFileReader = null;
    try {
        tesShaderFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tesShaderLocation));
        String line;
        while ((line = tesShaderFileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            tesShaderSource.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } finally {
        if (tesShaderFileReader != null) {
            try {
                tesShaderFileReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    BufferedReader tesscontrolShaderFileReader = null;
    try {
        tesscontrolShaderFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tesscontrolShaderLocation));
        String line;
        while ((line = tesscontrolShaderFileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            tesscontrolShaderSource.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } finally {
        if (tesscontrolShaderFileReader != null) {
            try {
                tesscontrolShaderFileReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    BufferedReader vertexShaderFileReader = null;
    try {
        vertexShaderFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(vertexShaderLocation));
        String line;
        while ((line = vertexShaderFileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            vertexShaderSource.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } finally {
        if (vertexShaderFileReader != null) {
            try {
                vertexShaderFileReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    BufferedReader fragmentShaderFileReader = null;
    try {
        fragmentShaderFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fragmentShaderLocation));
        String line;
        while ((line = fragmentShaderFileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            fragmentShaderSource.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } finally {
        if (fragmentShaderFileReader != null) {
            try {
                fragmentShaderFileReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    glShaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSource);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    System.out.println(glGetShaderi(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_TRUE);
    if (glGetShaderi(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("Vertex shader wasn't able to be compiled correctly. Error log:");
        //try{
        System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 1024));
        return -1;
    }
    glShaderSource(tesscontrolShader, tesscontrolShaderSource);
    glCompileShader(tesscontrolShader);
    System.out.println(glGetShaderi(tesscontrolShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_TRUE);
    if (glGetShaderi(tesscontrolShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("tesscontrol shader wasn't able to be compiled correctly. Error log:");
        System.err.println(GL11.glGetString(GL11.glGetError()));
        System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(tesscontrolShader, 1024));
    }
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSource);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    System.out.println(glGetShaderi(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_TRUE);
    if (glGetShaderi(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("Fragment shader wasn't able to be compiled correctly. Error log:");
        System.err.println(GL11.glGetString(GL11.glGetError()));
        System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 1024));
    }
    glShaderSource(tesShader, tesShaderSource);
    glCompileShader(tesShader);
    System.out.println(glGetShaderi(tesShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_TRUE);
    if (glGetShaderi(tesShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("Tessellation shader wasn't able to be compiled correctly. Error log:");
        System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(tesShader, 1024));
        return -1;
    }









    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, tesShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, tesscontrolShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    System.err.println(glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 1024));
    if (glGetProgrami(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
        System.err.println("Shader program wasn't linked correctly.");
        System.err.println(GL11.glGetString(GL11.glGetError()));
        System.exit(1);
        return -1;
    }
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    glDeleteShader(tesShader);
    glDeleteShader(tesscontrolShader);
    return shaderProgram;
}
```

My vertex shader is like this:

```
layout(triangles, equal_spacing, ccw) in;

uniform mat4 gVP;
uniform sampler2D gDisplacementMap;
uniform float gDispFactor;

in vec3 WorldPos_ES_in[];
in vec2 TexCoord_ES_in[];
in vec3 Normal_ES_in[];

out vec3 WorldPos_FS_in;
out vec2 TexCoord_FS_in;
out vec3 Normal_FS_in;

vec2 interpolate2D(vec2 v0, vec2 v1, vec2 v2)
{
return vec2(gl_TessCoord.x) * v0 + vec2(gl_TessCoord.y) * v1 + vec2(gl_TessCoord.z) * v2;
}

vec3 interpolate3D(vec3 v0, vec3 v1, vec3 v2)
{
return vec3(gl_TessCoord.x) * v0 + vec3(gl_TessCoord.y) * v1 + vec3(gl_TessCoord.z) * v2;
}

void main()
{
// Interpolate the attributes of the output vertex using the barycentric coordinates
TexCoord_FS_in = interpolate2D(TexCoord_ES_in[0], TexCoord_ES_in[1], TexCoord_ES_in[2]);
Normal_FS_in = interpolate3D(Normal_ES_in[0], Normal_ES_in[1], Normal_ES_in[2]);
Normal_FS_in = normalize(Normal_FS_in);
WorldPos_FS_in = interpolate3D(WorldPos_ES_in[0], WorldPos_ES_in[1], WorldPos_ES_in[2]);
// Displace the vertex along the normal
float Displacement = texture(gDisplacementMap, TexCoord_FS_in.xy).x;
WorldPos_FS_in += Normal_FS_in * Displacement * gDispFactor;
gl_Position = gVP * vec4(WorldPos_FS_in, 1.0);
}
```

Tessellation control shader:

```
// define the number of CPs in the output patch
layout (vertices = 3) out;

uniform vec3 gEyeWorldPos;

// attributes of the input CPs
in vec3 WorldPos_CS_in[];
in vec2 TexCoord_CS_in[];
in vec3 Normal_CS_in[];

// attributes of the output CPs
out vec3 WorldPos_ES_in[];
out vec2 TexCoord_ES_in[];
out vec3 Normal_ES_in[];

float GetTessLevel(float Distance0, float Distance1)
{
float AvgDistance = (Distance0 + Distance1) / 2.0;

if (AvgDistance <= 2.0) {
    return 10.0;
}
else if (AvgDistance <= 5.0) {
    return 7.0;
}
else {
    return 3.0;
}
}

void main()
{
// Set the control points of the output patch
TexCoord_ES_in[gl_InvocationID] = TexCoord_CS_in[gl_InvocationID];
Normal_ES_in[gl_InvocationID] = Normal_CS_in[gl_InvocationID];
WorldPos_ES_in[gl_InvocationID] = WorldPos_CS_in[gl_InvocationID];
// Calculate the distance from the camera to the three control points
float EyeToVertexDistance0 = distance(gEyeWorldPos, WorldPos_ES_in[0]);
float EyeToVertexDistance1 = distance(gEyeWorldPos, WorldPos_ES_in[1]);
float EyeToVertexDistance2 = distance(gEyeWorldPos, WorldPos_ES_in[2]);

// Calculate the tessellation levels
gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = GetTessLevel(EyeToVertexDistance1, EyeToVertexDistance2);
gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = GetTessLevel(EyeToVertexDistance2, EyeToVertexDistance0);
gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = GetTessLevel(EyeToVertexDistance0, EyeToVertexDistance1);
gl_TessLevelInner[0] = gl_TessLevelOuter[2];
}
```

Tessellation evaluation shader:

```
layout(triangles, equal_spacing, ccw) in;

uniform mat4 gVP;
uniform sampler2D gDisplacementMap;
uniform float gDispFactor;

in vec3 WorldPos_ES_in[];
in vec2 TexCoord_ES_in[];
in vec3 Normal_ES_in[];

out vec3 WorldPos_FS_in;
out vec2 TexCoord_FS_in;
out vec3 Normal_FS_in;

vec2 interpolate2D(vec2 v0, vec2 v1, vec2 v2)
{
return vec2(gl_TessCoord.x) * v0 + vec2(gl_TessCoord.y) * v1 + vec2(gl_TessCoord.z) * v2;
}

vec3 interpolate3D(vec3 v0, vec3 v1, vec3 v2)
{
return vec3(gl_TessCoord.x) * v0 + vec3(gl_TessCoord.y) * v1 + vec3(gl_TessCoord.z) * v2;
}

void main()
{
// Interpolate the attributes of the output vertex using the barycentric coordinates
TexCoord_FS_in = interpolate2D(TexCoord_ES_in[0], TexCoord_ES_in[1], TexCoord_ES_in[2]);
Normal_FS_in = interpolate3D(Normal_ES_in[0], Normal_ES_in[1], Normal_ES_in[2]);
Normal_FS_in = normalize(Normal_FS_in);
WorldPos_FS_in = interpolate3D(WorldPos_ES_in[0], WorldPos_ES_in[1], WorldPos_ES_in[2]);
// Displace the vertex along the normal
float Displacement = texture(gDisplacementMap, TexCoord_FS_in.xy).x;
WorldPos_FS_in += Normal_FS_in * Displacement * gDispFactor;
gl_Position = gVP * vec4(WorldPos_FS_in, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
varying vec4 position_in_view_space;
uniform sampler2D color_texture;

     void main()
     {
        float dist = distance(position_in_view_space, 
           vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
        if (dist < 1000.0)
        {
            gl_FragColor = gl_Color;
              // color near origin
        }
        else
        {
        gl_FragColor = gl_Color;
           //kill;
           //discard;
           //gl_FragColor = vec4(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0); 
              // color far from origin
        }
     }
```

I just cannot work out what is wrong. I know it is an issue with the shaders being linked but I cannot find why they crash java when they are linked, or how to fix it.

Would be great if someone could get them working as expected (Expected being that further away objects are given less vertices).

Comment: two lines below `glCompileShader(tesShader);` you test for the compile status of the vertexShader instead of the tesShader.

Comment: @BDL Happens ;). Thanks for the tip, anyway, as I never noticed. Unfortunately, that didn't fix my issue.

Comment: I told you it's a crash in the driver, did you even try to update your GPU drivers?

Comment: @PeterT This has nothing to do with the #version tags, which makes it unrelated to both the problem and solution of the other question I posted. Also, do I have to tell every player of my game to "Update their GPU drivers"? Because if so, that's a horrible idea.

Comment: @Joehot200 Yes, if the GPU driver is broken you do. It's not a rare problem to have especially if you use newer features like tessellation. Either you use old and stable features only at GL2.0 or 3.0 level or you deal with older drivers being broken.

Comment: @PeterT Okay. Are you able to point me in the correct direction for reducing the LOD per-vertex in OpenGL 3.2 and less? Also, I will update the GPU drivers.

Comment: You would do LOD as it has been done time in memoriam (what does "pre-vertex" even mean for LOD?). For meshes you create multiple levels with offline tools and swap them at appropriate distances (if you want to get fancy you blend the transition). For large terrain you do patches and swap those in (and hide the seems by adding polygons going straight down at the borders). You can also use geometry shaders for the terrain if you have access to 3.2

Comment: @PeterT per-vertex means per-vertex. As in, for every vertex. and not for every object.

Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I will probably try using geometry shaders, but if I cannot, will use that patch mechanism (Which I think will be near-impossible to implement.. But meh).

Thanks!